# Custom Formset :- Assigning foreign key value and inputting a field only once [ Logged in User ]

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a modelformset to populate the timetable model.

#### Models

```py
class Timetable(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey('Day',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    period = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    classteacher = models.ForeignKey('Class_teacher',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Class_teacher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    empid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

#### Views

```py
class Timetableadding(CreateView):
    model =  Timetable
    success_url = '/dashboard'
    form_class = Timetableform
    template_name = 'newtest.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Timetableadding, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = TimetableFormSet(queryset=Timetable.objects.none())
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = TimetableFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        formset.classteacher = get_object_or_404(Class_teacher, email=self.request.user.email)
        formset.save()
        # return super().form_valid(formset)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
```

#### Forms

```py
class Timetableform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = ( 'start', 'end', 'period')

TimetableFormSet = modelformset_factory(Timetable, fields=('start', 'end', 'period'),extra=8,)
```

#### Template

```html
<form class="form-material m-t-40 floating-labels" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ formset.management_form }}
     {% for form in formset %}
          {{ form }}<br><br>
     {% endfor %}
     <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-rounded btn-success">
                Submit
          </button>

      </div>
</form>
```

While populating the Timetableform using the createview view the fields `start end period` in `Timetable` model is done like a general form.

#### Requirements

1. The webapp has a login feature . When the user ( classteacher ) login they can add timetable. What I want is classteacher field in Timetable(model Form ) should be automatically set as user which is the classteacher. ( Classteacher ) and should be saved in the db after creating the timetable. Classteacher model is updated with respective required fields .

I tried passing classteacher to formset , but it was execute as I need

> I know how to do within a normal form , But I have not done this in a formset.

2. The day field in the `Timetable` should be selected only once , so there will be 8 forms to supply `start` `end` and `period` but there should be only one form to supply `day`. I succeeded in dealing 8 form for `start` `end` and `period` but unaware about the `day`.

Comment: If you use an `inlineformset_factory` you can pass the teacher instance to which the form set belongs to directly when initializing the formset. See [the example here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: The alternative is looping through the forms: `instances = formset.save(commit=False); for instance in instances: instance.classteacher = ...; instance.save()`

Comment: thanks a lot , is there any work around for the second requirement ?

Comment: Add another form (just simple Django `Form` with a `day` field) to your context, verify it's valid together with the formset and in the `form_valid` method, assign `day_form.cleaned_data['day']` to each instance of the formset before saving (i.e. loop like I said in my second comment).

Comment: Can you deliver it as an answer , I didn't get adding another form to context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do this:

- If you use an `inlineformset_factory` you can pass the teacher instance to which the form set belongs to directly when initializing the formset. See the example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).
- Or you can loop through the forms in order to modify the instances before they are saved:

  ```
  instances = formset.save(commit=False)
  for instance in instances: 
      instance.classteacher = ...
      instance.save()
  ```

If you want the user to submit an extra field that is common to all instances, you can add another form to your view:

```
class DayForm(forms.Form):
    day = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Day.objects.all())

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    context['day_form'] = DayForm()
    return context

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    day_form = DayForm(data=request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid() and day_form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(formset, day_form)

def form_valid(self, formset, day_form):
    day = day_form.cleaned_data['day']
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
        instance.day = day
        instance.teacher = ...
        instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

#### Template to render

```html
<form class="form-material m-t-40 floating-labels" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ day_form }} <br>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
     {{ form }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
     <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-rounded btn-success">
    Submit
          </button>

     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ```__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'```

It is raising the above error for ```day_form = DayForm(queryset=..., data=request.POST)```

Comment: My bad. That was a typo.

Comment: is it possible to render list of foreingkeys and create object in createview ? 
i have a question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304473/render-a-list-of-foreign-key-in-template

Answer (score 0):

In your CreateView you could override get_initial method:

```py
def get_initial(self):
    self.initial = CreateView.get_initial(self)
    self.initial["classteacher"] = self.request.user
return self.initial.copy()
```

Then you need to add this field to your form

```py
class Timetableform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = ( 'start', 'end', 'period', “classteacher”)
```

if you dont want to show this field in your form and still add classteacher as a current user you could use Hiddeninput widget with this field:

```py
class Timetableform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = ( 'start', 'end', 'period', “classteacher”)
           widgets = {"classteacher": HiddenInput}
```

in the formset you could use hiddeninput widget as well or use form=Timetableform argument in the constructor. Same idea

Comment: This is not working , I have a similar question for forms and its has a more flexible answer saving an object 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899282/assign-foreign-key-value-after-creating-logged-in-user/55899387#answer-55899359 , similarly saving the object is required , and I have one more requirement mentioned in the question> The day field in the Timetable should be selected only once , so there will be 8 forms to supply start end and period but there should be only one form to supply day. I succeeded in dealing 8 form for start end and period but unaware about the day.