# Render a list of foreign key in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

#### Models

```py
class Head_of_department(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name 

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Attendance(models.Model):
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=attendance_choices, blank=True)
```

#### Views

```py
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['employee']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get_context_data(self,** kwargs):
        context = super(Attendancecreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        context["objects"] = self.model.objects.filter(employee__head_of_department =hod)
        print (context["objects"])
        return context

     def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.head_of_department = get_object_or_404(Head_of_department, email=self.request.user.email)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#### Template

```html
<div class="form-group">
        {% for item in objects %}
            {{ item.employee }}
        {% endfor %}

</div>
```

The webapp has a login feature. The headofdepartment can mark the attendance . I want to render a list of employees under the respective logged in HOD and mark attendance . I want to do this in the same view .

I am unable to render the employees for logged in HOD.

Comment: Exactly which table you want to show in templates ?

Comment: Now in template you can render data from Attendance table, and all associated from Head_of_department and Employee.

Comment: I want to render the list of employees and mark attendance in one view . List of employees has to be listed in the create view of attendance

Comment: {% for item in objects %} {{ item.employee.first_name }} {% endfor %}

Comment: i have tried that , it never worked

Comment: ah... okay. If i understand correctly, I will add answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , I wrote views incorrectly.

```py
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['employee']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get_context_data(self,** kwargs):
        context = super(Attendancecreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        context["objects"] = Employee.objects.filter(head_of_department =hod)
        print (context["objects"])
        return context
```

#### Template

```html
{% for emp in objects %}
            {{ emp.first_name }}  {{ emp.last_name }}
 {% endfor %}
```